# How to get the Sum of Lowest values in 3 rows each added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The following code will get the lowest value entered in first 3 columns, it is running fine. But after adding the row (Add Row) i am unable to get the lowest value from next 3 columns. Also i want to get the sum of all 3 lowest values from as much columns as user will add. Your kind help is required in this regard.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#Add_BDSP").click(function() {
    $('#BDSP' + i).html("<td><input type='text' name='QuotedAmount1[" + i + "]' placeholder='Quoted Amount' class='form-control' /><input type='text' name='QuotedAmount2[" + i + "]'placeholder='Quoted Amount' class='form-control' /><input type='text' name='QuotedAmount3[" + i + "]' placeholder='Quoted Amount' class='form-control'/></td>");

    $('#Tab_BDSP').append('<tr id="BDSP' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
    i++;
  });
  $("#Delete_BDSP").click(function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      $("#BDSP" + (i - 1)).html('');
      i--;
    }
  });

});

var input = $('[name="QuotedAmount1[0]"],[name="QuotedAmount2[0]"],[name="QuotedAmount3[0]"]'),

  QuotedAmount1 = $('[name="QuotedAmount1[0]"]'),
  QuotedAmount2 = $('[name="QuotedAmount2[0]"]'),
  QuotedAmount3 = $('[name="QuotedAmount3[0]"]'),

  MulRes = $('[name="ServiceTotalCost"]');


input.change(function() {
  var Qoute1 = (isNaN(parseInt(QuotedAmount1.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(QuotedAmount1.val());
  var Qoute2 = (isNaN(parseInt(QuotedAmount2.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(QuotedAmount2.val());
  var Qoute3 = (isNaN(parseInt(QuotedAmount3.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(QuotedAmount3.val());



  MulRes.val(Math.min(Qoute1, Qoute2, Qoute3));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-float">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="Tab_BDSP">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Amount</td>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id='BDSP0'>


        <td>
          <input type="text" name='QuotedAmount1[0]' placeholder='Quoted Amount' class="form-control" required />
          <input type="text" name='QuotedAmount2[0]' placeholder='Quoted Amount' class="form-control" required />
          <input type="text" name='QuotedAmount3[0]' placeholder='Quoted Amount' class="form-control" required />
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr id='BDSP1'></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<a id="Add_BDSP" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='Delete_BDSP' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">

  <div class="input-group form-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">business_center</i>
                                                </span>
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="ServiceTotalCost" id="ServiceTotalCost" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> But after adding the row (Add Row) i am unable to get the lowest value
>   from next 3 columns

Your main problem is:

```
QuotedAmount1 = $('[name="QuotedAmount1[0]"]'),
QuotedAmount2 = $('[name="QuotedAmount2[0]"]'),
QuotedAmount3 = $('[name="QuotedAmount3[0]"]'),
```

Because you just select `QuotedAmount1[0]` to `QuotedAmount3[0]`, after you append `row` new `input` has `QuotedAmount1[1]` .. , also you used `change` and for new row you need to use `change` with `document` selector, to get live `change`. And you should move your variable inside of `change` event. Important things is, you should select your input without `name`, here is working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#Add_BDSP").click(function() {
    $('#BDSP' + i).html("<td><input type='text' name='QuotedAmount1[" + i + "]' placeholder='Quoted Amount' class='form-control' /><input type='text' name='QuotedAmount2[" + i + "]'placeholder='Quoted Amount' class='form-control' /><input type='text' name='QuotedAmount3[" + i + "]' placeholder='Quoted Amount' class='form-control'/></td>");

    $('#Tab_BDSP').append('<tr id="BDSP' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
    i++;
  });
  $("#Delete_BDSP").click(function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      $("#BDSP" + (i - 1)).html('');
      i--;
    }
  });

});



$(document).on('change', '#Tab_BDSP tbody tr td input[type="text"]', function() {
  let result = 0;
  var MulRes = $('input#ServiceTotalCost');

  var QuotedAmount1 = $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]').eq(0),
    QuotedAmount2 = $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]').eq(1),
    QuotedAmount3 = $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]').eq(2);

  var Qoute1 = (isNaN(parseInt(QuotedAmount1.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(QuotedAmount1.val()),
    Qoute2 = (isNaN(parseInt(QuotedAmount2.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(QuotedAmount2.val()),
    Qoute3 = (isNaN(parseInt(QuotedAmount3.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(QuotedAmount3.val());

  var min = Math.min(Qoute1, Qoute2, Qoute3);
  $(this).parent().attr('data-lowest', min)


  $('#Tab_BDSP tbody tr td').each(function() {
    result += +$(this).attr('data-lowest')
  });

  MulRes.val(result)
});
```

```css
Thank you for kind response,
the code is running perfect,
but the issue is if i change the value in additional rows,
it adds the lowest into the sum,
e.g. 1st row have 300000 400000 500000 and second row have 600000 700000 800000 The total sum will be 900000 which is perfect. but if i change the value from 600000 to 200000 it should shows 700000 but it gives value of 1100000. Your kind help is needed to rectify this issue in the given code. – ADIL I.T 8 mins ago
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-float">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="Tab_BDSP">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Amount</td>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id='BDSP0'>


        <td>
          <input type="text" name='QuotedAmount1[0]' placeholder='Quoted Amount' class="form-control" required />
          <input type="text" name='QuotedAmount2[0]' placeholder='Quoted Amount' class="form-control" required />
          <input type="text" name='QuotedAmount3[0]' placeholder='Quoted Amount' class="form-control" required />
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr id='BDSP1'></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<a id="Add_BDSP" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='Delete_BDSP' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">

  <div class="input-group form-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">business_center</i>
                                                </span>
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="ServiceTotalCost" id="ServiceTotalCost" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Also i want to get the sum of all 3 lowest values from as much columns
>   as user will add

For get `sum` you need to get `min` and also old lowest value

Comment: Thank you for kind response, the code is running perfect, but the issue is if i change the value in additional rows, it adds the lowest into the sum, e.g.
1st row have
300000
400000
500000

and second row have 
600000
700000
800000

The total sum will be 900000 which is perfect. but if i change the value from 600000 to 200000 it should shows 700000 but it gives value of 1100000.
Your kind help is needed to rectify this issue in the given code.

Comment: @ADILI.T check updated answer please, is it solve your issue?

Comment: I am trying to integrate this code it in my template it is not working. the last code you have given works fine with my template

Comment: I am trying to integrate this code it in my template it is not working. the last code you have given works fine with my template

Comment: @ADILI.T If your problem solved, please accept  answer and if you like +1 vote-up. good luck

Answer (score 0):

This code works. I just made all of the script run separately so it worked.

```js
$(".input0").keyup(function() {

  var val10 = $("[name='a1[0]']").val();
  var val20 = $("[name='a2[0]']").val();
  var val30 = $("[name='a3[0]']").val();

  var lowestValue0 = Math.min(val10, val20, val30);
  $("[name='answer[0]']").val(lowestValue0);
  $("[name='total']").val(lowestValue0);

});


$(document).keyup(function() {

  var sum = "";
  $('.inputClass').each(function() {
    sum += this.value;
  });
  $("[name='total']").val(sum);

});

$(document).ready(function() {

  var a = "1";

  $(".add").click(function() {

    $('<div class="valueDiv' + a + '"><input name="a1[' + a + ']" class="input' + a + '" placeholder="Value 1"><input name="a2[' + a + ']" class="input' + a + '" placeholder="Value 2"><input name="a3[' + a + ']" class="input' + a + '" placeholder="Value 3"><br><h5>Lowest Value = <\/h5><input name="answer[' + a + ']" class="inputClass" readonly placeholder="Lowest Value"><hr><\/div>').appendTo("#mainDiv");

    $('#scripts').append('<script type="text/javascript" id="script' + a + '">$(".input' + a + '").keyup(function() { var val1' + a + ' = $("[name=\'a1[' + a + ']\']").val(); var val2' + a + ' = $("[name=\'a2[' + a + ']\']").val(); var val3' + a + ' = $("[name=\'a3[' + a + ']\']").val(); var lowestValue' + a + ' = Math.min(val1' + a + ', val2' + a + ', val3' + a + '); $("[name=\'answer[' + a + ']\']").val(lowestValue' + a + '); });<\/script>');

    a++;

  });

  $(".delete").click(function() {

    if (a > 1) {
      $(".valueDiv" + (a - 1)).remove();
      $("script" + (a - 1)).remove();
      a--;
    }

    var sum = "";
    $('.inputClass').each(function() {
      sum += this.value;
    });
    $("[name='total']").val(sum);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="mainDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 50px;">
  <div class="valueDiv0">
    <hr>
    <input name="a1[0]" class="input0" placeholder="Value 1">
    <input name="a2[0]" class="input0" placeholder="Value 2">
    <input name="a3[0]" class="input0" placeholder="Value 3">
    <br>
    <h5>Lowest Value = </h5>
    <input name="answer[0]" class="inputClass" readonly placeholder="Lowest Value">
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px 50px;">
  <h5>Sum of All Lowest Values</h5>
  <input style="width: 230px;" name="total" readonly placeholder="Total Value of All Lowest Values">
</div>
<div id="scripts">

</div>
<br>
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary add">Add Row</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger delete">Delete Row</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```